# How to use ORDER BY along with UNION ALL in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables which I need to combine using `UNION ALL`.

Assume that table (T1,T2,T3) contains columns as follows:

Table T1

```
Name, Qty, Amt, EXP
```

Table T2

```
Qty, Amt, EXP, SRNO
```

Table T3

```
Name, Qty, EXP
```

My query is something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Qty, Amt, EXP 
FROM T1

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL AS Name, Qty, Amt, EXP 
FROM T2 
ORDER BY SRNO

UNION ALL

SELECT Name, Qty, NULL Amt, EXP 
FROM T3
```

I also tried

```
SELECT Name, Qty, Amt, EXP
FROM T1

UNION ALL

SELECT Name, Qty, Amt, Exp 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM T2 
     ORDER BY SRNO) AS T21

UNION ALL

SELECT Name, Qty, NULL Amt, EXP
FROM T3
```

The result from T2 is uneven and I want to sort it by SRNO(integer) but I get errors when using unions.

**NOTE** I don't want to take `SRNO` in `UNION ALL`, I just need it to sort the data

Comment: What do you mean by `TABLE T3
COLUMNS ARE : (Name, Qty, NULL Amt, 'EXP')` ? What is `NULL` column ?

Comment: Oh, actually I took null as column, Sorry I edit the question again.

Comment: 2 of the 3 tables _don't_ have an `SRNO` column.  What value(s) should we use for sorting in these two tables, in lieu of `SRNO` ?

Comment: Yea T1 and T3 don't have SRNO column. I actually wanted T1 data on first, T2 data after that and T3 data at last.

Comment: You have to declare a sort order for the result of *all rows in the union*. You may not "want" SRNO in the union but if it helps to define the ordering for the whole set, you *need* it there. Union all does *not* guarantee that all of the `T1` data will come first nor that the `T3` data comes last.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Na I don't want to sort the whole set. T1 data - T2 data(sorted) - T3 Data. Moreover, T1 and T3 will have one result row all the time.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so is there any other possible way to get all data in order.
Joins will be huge to fetch data for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try adding two sort columns explicitly to your current union query:

```sql
SELECT Name, Qty, Amt, Exp
FROM
(
    SELECT Name, Qty, Amt, 'EXP' AS Exp, 1 AS p1, 1 AS p2 FROM T1  -- place this row 1st
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, Qty, Amt, Exp, 2, SRNO FROM T2                    -- middle
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, Qty, NULL, 'EXP', 3, 1 FROM T3                    -- place this row 3rd
) t
ORDER BY
    p1, p2;
```

Here we add two dummy sorting levels to the union query.  The `p1` sorting level puts the single record from `T1` first, the single record from `T3` last, and the records from `T2` in the middle.  Then, the second sorting level `p2` sorts the `T2` records ascending by the `SRNO`.  If `SRNO` is not an integer column, then we would have to make slight changes to the above answer, but it should still work.